# How can I crawl all data with split?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, split, web-crawler

Crawling data like this

```
abc | abc | ab

ab  | abc | abc

ab  | ab

abc | ab

abc | abc | abc
```

using split and if on python

```py
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser'
book_pages = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'txt lastCol'})

print(book_pages[1].text.split("|")[0])
b_page.append(book_pages[1].text.split("|")[0])

if book_pages[1].text.split("|")[1] != None:
  print(book_pages[1].text.split("|")[1].strip())
  b_weight.append(book_pages[1].text.split("|")[1].strip())

    if book_pages[1].text.split("|")[2] != None:
      print(book_pages[1].text.split("|")[2].strip())
      b_size.append(book_pages[1].text.split("|")[2].strip())

    else:
      continue
else:
 continue
```

but error says ***IndexError: list index out of range***

How can I crawl all data without error??

Comment: Can you share the URL of the page and what data do you want to get?

Comment: http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001016003008?ParamSortTp=04 it's not eng site. I'm using selenium and click all results and crawl Number of feet, weight, size.

Comment: you could add a try except blog. At which line you get an error?

Comment: if book_pages[1].text.split("|")[2].strip()
 at this line I got error

Comment: Given your sample data, what exactly is your expected output?